# Laravel 5.6 post login redirect to login page

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

SOLVED

SOLUTION
the problem is a primary key using on table of database i only pass the name of the primary key to attribute $primarykey in the model

I develop a login system for my laravel application with a table different of a users table aparently the login works fine, but if i use the redirect and the middleware auth to protect my routes i have a problem to enter on the route because on post login the app redirect to protected route and on enter in the protected route the app return to login, but the users credentials are correct.

**My Model Users**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $table = 'pessoas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome_completo', 'email', 'password',
    ];



    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Login method**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        //$email = $request->input('email');
        //$password = $request->input('password'));

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            //return Auth::user()->nome_completo;
            return redirect()->intended('/usuario/home');
        }
    }
```

**Routes with middleware and login**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/usuario/home', 'Usuarios\UsuarioController@renderHome')->name('home');

    Route::get('/usuario/perfil', function () {
        return view('usuario.meuperfil');
    })->name('perfil');

    Route::get('/usuario/estoque', function () {
        return view('usuario.estoque');
    })->name('estoque');

    Route::get('/usuario/fotos', function () {
        return view('usuario.fotos');
    })->name('fotos');

    Route::get('/usuario/carrinho', function () {
        return view('usuario.carrinho');
    })->name('carrinho');

    Route::get('/usuario/orcamentos', function () {
        return view('usuario.orcamentos');
    })->name('orcamentos');

    Route::get('/usuario/enviados', function () {
        return view('usuario.enviados');
    })->name('enviados');

    Route::get('/usuario/tickets', function () {
        return view('usuario.tickets');
    })->name('tickets');

    Route::get('/usuario/calculadora', function () {
        return view('usuario.calculadora');
    })->name('calculadora');

    Route::get('/usuario/tutorial', function () {
        return view('usuario.tutorial');
    })->name('tutorial');
});



Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('usuario.login');
})->name('login');

Route::post('/login', 'Usuarios\UsuarioController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Usuarios\UsuarioController@logout')->name('logout');
```

what is the solution of the problem?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

What's your "login" middleware? Isn't it should be "Auth" middleware? I think the reason is your middleware.Because you jump to protect routes means your "attempt" function has been successful.

Comment: the login middleware is a custom middleware is a custom middleware that i create to test, but the result is the same of the euth middleware redirect back to login route after post login